# Defining dependencies between 3rd party requirejs amd and non-amd modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, js-amd

I am using angularjs with requirejs and I have no trouble to load my own amd modules in the correct order. I am also able to load 3rd party (bower) dependencies for my own amd modules if the dependencies are non-amd using shims as shown in [requirejs documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

Now I have a 3rd-party amd-module [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) that would have angularjs as dependency. Since I am not allowed to use shims for amd-modules how can I tell requirejs to load angular-spinner only after angular was loaded?

Currently I am getting an exception saying that angular is undefined when angular-spinner is loaded.

Comment: What version of angular-spinner are you loading? It recently went through a major reimplementation in TypeScript and this may have an impact on answers.

Comment: If "angular-spinner" is AMDfied, it should already have an dependency on angularjs, check if the the dependency name is the same as your dependency/module id for angular...

Comment: @Louis, I was using angular-spinner 0.0.8, but it wasn't an angular-spinner problem

Comment: @Legends, you were right. My angularjs shim went by the name 'angularjs' but angular-spinner expected 'angular'